# Cannot connect as Guest to ubuntu usershare from MAC OSX Yosemite?

Tags: 14.04, server, samba, mac, guest-session

I cannot connect to my shared folders on my Ubuntu server from my Mac.

My Windows computer can connect without any problems.

Giving Ubuntu credentials as opposed to using "Anonymous" used to work, but that has stopped working as well...

When I try connecting to my Ubuntu server `smb://192.168.0.100/` as a Guest from my Mac I get:

```
"There was a problem connecting to the server “192.168.0.100”. Check the server name or IP address, and then try again. If you continue to have problems, contact your system administrator."
```

These are my `testparm` results

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[profiles]"
WARNING: No path in service profiles - making it unavailable!
NOTE: Service profiles is flagged unavailable.
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[print$]"
Processing section "[Alba]"
Processing section "[AS2]"
Processing section "[scan]"
Processing section "[public]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
    workgroup = ALBA
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0
    bind interfaces only = Yes
    security = USER
    map to guest = Bad User
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    dns proxy = No
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    guest ok = Yes


[profiles]
    available = No


[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/spool/samba
    create mask = 0700
    printable = Yes
    browseable = No


[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[Alba]
    path = /home/administrator/Alba
    read only = No


[AS2]
    path = /home/administrator/AS2
    read only = No


[scan]
    path = /home/scan
    read only = No


[public]
    path = /home
    read only = No
```

Answer (score 2):

Due to the recent fixes for the Badlock Samba vulnerability, and many of the changes necessary to address it, there are a large number of regressions.  This is one of the things hit by the regressions as a result of the fix.  (It is not likely a case of your configuration being wrong)

There is a bug open on this [on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1572301), but as of yet there is no fix.  There is no workarounds for this issue yet, either, so there is currently no way to 'fix' this issue.

> This post may be updated in the future if this changes, and if a fix is made available.